# Is there a way to fetch all license header from Cocoapods

Tags: ios, cocoapods, podspec

I use Cocoapods to integrate my workspace. I have about 45 pods that I use in my project. I would like to attribute all the license headers and was wondering is there a way I can fetch and concatenate all the headers or should I do it manually?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A file with this information is actually generated by default by CocoaPods. This file is generated under `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods-Acknowledgements.plist`. You can then add a `post_install` hook in your `Podfile` to copy this to somewhere where you can use it. Here's the official example:

```
post_install do | installer |
  require 'fileutils'
  FileUtils.cp_r('Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods-Acknowledgements.plist', 'Resources/Settings.bundle/Acknowledgements.plist', :remove_destination => true)
end
```

Read all about this on [the wiki page](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/wiki/Acknowledgements)

Comment: For version 0.39.0, the 'acknowledgements' is lowercase. For example: `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods-acknowledgements.plist`